# WSO2 developer studio - display whole orchestration in one window including receive sequences

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

we've multiple sequences, endpoints, APIs etc in the synapse-config folder. Is there a way to graphically see the complete orchestration defined in the API XML in wso2 developer studio.

The API XML implements a service chaining scenario, where the sequence mediators are used in the 'receive' property of send mediators.

Right now, we're able to see each of the API XMLs, Sequence XMLs etc separately, but would like to see everything in one window.

Answer (score 0):

service chaining are can be extremely complex as well as simple. also if you use class mediators what are you doing inside is invisible to outer layer as those are completely java code. so representation would be wrong.
Answer for your question is NO up to current release.